# IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'example.property' in string value "${example.property}"

Tags: spring-boot

I was using spring boot 1.4.0 there **everything was working fine** but I updated spring boot to 1.4.2 and booom following exception occurred.

> IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'example.property' in string value "${example.property}"

Again I downgrade version to 1.4.0 it was working.

I have placed properties file outside jar and I used `spring.config.location` to provide `example.yml` file path where I kept properties with help of STS(eclipse) run configuration.

Parameter Name : **spring.config.location**

Value : **file:/home/project/application-property.yml,file:/home/project/email-property.yml**

Following is usage of property in spring,

```
@Service("myService")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

  @Value("${example.property}")
  private String someProperty;

  ....
}
```

Following is my application class (not single xml file I have used for config),

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebApplication
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

Is there any changes in spring-boot 1.4.2 related properties access. What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Could you please share your bootstrap.yml,Application.yml in your config.location and pom.xml so that we can analyse the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Following solution worked for me,

STS/eclipse run configuration added run time parameters,

*Parameter Name* : **run.arguments**

*Value* : **"--spring.config.location=file:/home/project/application-property.yml", "--spring.config.location=file:/home/project/mail-property.yml"**

> NOTE : If you look values its double quoted comma seperated list of files

But really don't know why this solution is working and not one in question. Please do comment if know reason for this.